# drupal 7 FAPI- ajax change event not working with textfield

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

How do you use ajax change event to get and display the value of textfield at real time (i.e. on every value change new value is displayed). I've tried the following but it seems that `#ajax['event']='change'` isn't working with textfield. Ajax call is only triggered when the textfield loses focus e.g. when I write Hello in the textfield, it isn't displayed until I click outside of the textfield. Here is my code:-

```
function test1_form($form, &$form_state)
{
   $form['text']=array(
         '#title'=>'Text:',
         '#type'=> 'textfield',
         '#ajax'=> array(
            'event'=>'change',
            'callback'=>'test1_form_submit',
            'wrapper'=>'contnr',
            'method'=>'replace',
        ),
    );

   $form['up_button']=array(
      '#title'=>t('Preview:'),
      '#type'=>'markup',
      '#prefix'=>'<div id="contnr">',
      '#suffix'=>'</div>',
      '#markup'=>'<h2>This is to be replaced</h2>',
   );
   return $form;
}

function test1_form_submit($form, $form_state)
{       
  return $form_state['values']['text'];
}
```

Is there a way to get value of the textfield at real time and display back it in the browser in drupal 7 module???

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result using jQuery's [keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event.

Code sample:

```
jQuery("#textFieldID").keydown(function(e) {
    jQuery("#contnr").html("<h2>" + jQuery(this).val() + "</h2>");

    // the above line can be broken into 2 lines as follows:
    var myVal = jQuery(this).val(); // grab the textfield value
    jQuery("#contnr").html("<h2>" + myVal + "</h2>"); // set the value to the div
});
```

Update:

You can copy the js code into a `.js` file (call it `my-script.js` and place it into your module's directory) and then use [#attached](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) property to add the javascript file to the page as follows:

```
function test1_form($form, &$form_state)
{
   $form['text']=array(
         '#title'=>'Text:',
         '#type'=> 'textfield',
         '#ajax'=> array(
            'event'=>'change',
            'callback'=>'test1_form_submit',
            'wrapper'=>'contnr',
            'method'=>'replace',
        ),
    );

   $form['up_button']=array(
      '#title'=>t('Preview:'),
      '#type'=>'markup',
      '#prefix'=>'<div id="contnr">',
      '#suffix'=>'</div>',
      '#markup'=>'<h2>This is to be replaced</h2>',
   );

   // the only code you need to add.
   $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
       drupal_get_path('module', 'test1') . '/my-script.js',
   );

   return $form;
}
```

Hope this solves your issue... Muhammad.

Comment: OK. Can you please tell how I can combine this code with my above drupal module's code. I mean in which function I should place it and I've to store the returned value of the textfield in a variable and then use it. Is this correct: `$value=drupal_add_js('jQuery("#textFieldID").keydown(function(e) {
    jQuery("#contnr").html(jQuery(this).val());
});`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Kindly recheck (from the beginning).

Comment: I'd loose the AJAX all together and do this on the client side only with Muhammad's suggestion.  Otherwise you're doing a round trip to the server for every key press, which will be bad for performance in many ways.

Comment: @MuhammadReda I've tried exactly as you suggested but its not working and also I need the textfield value in the submit handler where I've to do some processing on it. How can I pass the variable `myVAl` to the submit function on the server???

Comment: @ChrisMiller Yes, you are right. I also think so but actually I've to grab that text from textfield, write it on an image using imagemagick and then dispaly it on browser, it is currently done on blur event but I want to do it with change event on textfield. Is it possible on the client side???

Comment: You may be able to do it with the HTML canvas element in newer browsers.  You'll need to provide a fallback.  In that case, I'd use onblur because onkeydown is going to kill performance.  Especially if you're generating an image on every key press.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim make sure you type the CORRECT text field id inside `jQuery("#textFieldID")` instead of `#textFieldID`.

Comment: @MuhammadReda I don't know how to find the id of a form element however I picked it from the corresponding generated HTML in page source. Is it OK???

Comment: That's how you should do it. Does it work now ?! if it doesn't, make sure that the js file you added gets added to the page. (add something like `alert("test")` to your js file). If worked, then make sure you have the right text field id (add this `alert(jQuery("#textFieldID").size())` to your js file) it should return `1` if you use the correct text field id.